# Invalid qualifier when pressing command button

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is suppose to verify if the range of column 23 has only numeric values. When pressing the command button, I get the error **Invalid Qualifier** on the row `If Not IsNumeric(sh1.Cells(k, 23)).Value Then`. Any help to fix the problem will be must appreciated. Please find the code attached below.

Note: the code needs to be under a command button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim k As Long
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, wb1 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set sh1 = wb1.Worksheets(1)


    Application.EnableEvents = False


For k = 5 To 1000

        If Not IsNumeric(sh1.Cells(k, 23)).Value Then
                sh1.Cells(k, 23).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ElseIf sh1.Cells(k, 23).Value = "" Then
                sh1.Cells(k, 23).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        Else
                sh1.Cells(k, 23).Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(sh1.Cells(k, 23).Value, 0)
                sh1.Cells(k, 23).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If


        Next k
        Application.EnableEvents = True



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the bracket in the wrong place - it should be:

```
If Not IsNumeric(sh1.Cells(k, 23).Value) Then
```